# How can I have multiple navigation paths with Django, like a simplifies wizard path and a full path?

Tags: python, django, redirect, path, django-templates

Lets say I have an application with a structure such as:

```
System
  set date
  set name
  set something
Other
  set death ray target
  calibrate
```

and I want to have "back" and "next" buttons on a page. The catch is, if you're going in via the "wizard", I want the nav path to be something like "set name" -> "set death ray target" -> "set name". If you go via the Advanced options menu, I want to just iterate options... "set date" -> "set name" -> "set something" -> "set death ray target" -> calibrate.

So far, I'm thinking I have to use different URIs, but that's that. Any ideia how this could be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [django form wizard](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/).